# tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: lazy loading problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder, lazy-loading

While implementing TableView I've stuck with the problem that I somehow has broken "lazy" loading behaviour of UITableView. Now upon entering the screen it loads all the cells (both visible and invisible).

Could someone point out where I should look at?
In IB I have such an organization:

-> UIView

--> UIScrollView

---> UITableView

---> UIImageView

---> etc

Could this be a problem?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your table view in a scroll view? That probably isn't necessary and would lead to the problem you describe if its content size is configured to be taller than the screen.

Comment: My screen has lots of other controls/views besides the tableview, positioned higher. How should I organize all of it, so it could be scrollable? Is it possible to add all other views into UITableView and remove UIScrollView at all? Thnx

Comment: Why was this downvoted...? It's a perfectly reasonable and above-average decently described question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself. I am a bit new to iOS/OSX development (i.e. question is n00b :).

It appears that UITableView has to manage scrolling, otherwise it doesn't know which cells are visible, it looks into its frame property and draws cell which are visible in its view.

So, now I've got this IB config for a screen:

-> UITableView

--> UIView

---> UIImageView

---> all other views

That seems to be right.